# Convert char[] to LPCWSTR

Tags: visual-c++

Can anyone help me to correct this code:

```
    char szBuff[64];
    sprintf(szBuff, "%p", m_hWnd);
    MessageBox(NULL, szBuff, L"Test print handler", MB_OK);
```

The error is, it cant convert the 2nd parameter to LPCWSTR.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this *specific* case, the fix is quite simple:

```
wchar_t szBuff[64];
swprintf(szBuff, L"%p", m_hWnd);
MessageBox(NULL, szBuff, L"Test print handler", MB_OK);
```

That is, use Unicode strings throughout. In general, when programming on Windows, using `wchar_t` and UTF-16 is probably the simplest. It depends on how much interaction with other systems you have to do, of course.

For the general case, if you've got an ASCII (or `char *`) string, use either [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the general case, or `mbstowcs` as @Matthew points out for simpler cases (`mbstowcs` works if the string is in the current C locale).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [mbstowcs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mbstowcs.html), which will convert a conventional "one byte per character" string to a "multiple byte per character" string.

Alternatively, change your project settings to use Multibyte Strings - by default they are usually "Unicode" or "Wide Character" strings (I can't remember the exact option name off the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling with `UNICODE`, make all the strings you work with double width - i.e. define them as `wchar_t*`.

If you really must convert ASCII to Unicode, use [ATL conversion macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since your tag suggests VC++, I am suggesting CString. If yes, then the following snippet will also work for your case:

```
CString szBuff;

szBuff.Format(_T("%p"), m_hWnd);
MessageBox(NULL, szBuff, L"Test print handler", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **MultiByteToWideChar()** works for me:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 ...
 wchar_t filename[4096] = {0};
 MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), filename, strlen(argv[1]));

 // RenderFile() requires LPCWSTR (or wchar_t*, respectively)
 hr = pGraph->RenderFile(filename, NULL);
 ...
}
```