# I have errors using GetFullPathName

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use `GetFullPathName` to get the full path of a file, but I have errors. The error is:

> cannot convert argument 1 from "char *" to 'LPCWSTR'.

Could someone help me?  Here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* fileExt;
    char szDir[256];
    GetFullPathName(argv[0], 256, szDir, &fileExt);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225682/convert-char-to-lpcwstr

Comment: I find all these other questions using google. Why can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you using ANSI strings instead of UNICODE-UTF16. The main solution is to use `TCHAR` compatible entry point `_tmain`, it will be compatible either with UNICODE or ANSI consider project settings as the same  `GetFullPathName` will be  `GetFullPathNameA` for ANSI configuration and  `GetFullPathNameW` for UNICODE.

Example

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR* fileExt;
    TCHAR szDir[256];

    GetFullPathName(argv[0], 256, szDir, &fileExt);

    return 0;
}
```

To display ANSI or UNICODE string to your program you may use this statement in the begining of your main function

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
#define consoleOut  std::wcout
#else
#define consoleOut  std::cout
#endif
```

than display your strings as

```
consoleOut << szDir << std::endl;
```

the overall program will be

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
#define consoleOut  std::wcout
#else
#define consoleOut  std::cout
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR* fileExt;
    TCHAR szDir[256];

    GetFullPathName(argv[0], 256, szDir, &fileExt);

    consoleOut << szDir << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the result.

[image]

Comment: Yes, now i don`t have any errors, but when i ran, my output is a adress suchs us: 001BFBE8

Comment: @Sebi95: How did you output your string?

Comment: @Sebi95: It is certanly because you using a wrong version of output string (possible ASCII only compatible `printf` or `cout`.

Comment: How should i make the output?

Comment: No, my output is made with cout, as u said. How should i do?

Comment: @Sebi95:  Wait for a minute.

Comment: I've tried with wcout, but it doesn`t show anything at the console.

Comment: You should say ANSI, not ASCII. ANSI means any one of several characters sets with between 128 and 256 characters. Which character set it is depends on the OS language/user language and can be changed by the process or thread. (It's probably not [code page 20127](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: I rlly thx u for trying to help me, but my code refuses to work...it works with that wcout, but the output is nothing...

Comment: @Sebi95: Its realy strange that it not works. Did you try to output incoming `arg[0]` without getting full path?

Comment: @Sebi95: If you didnot suppose to use your application in unicode environment you can still disable it. And work with ASCII or MBCS.

Comment: The idea is that i didn`t need to use it in unicode environment but i was asking to make a function for getting the full path of a file, and i made what i shew to you. I need tchar for getfullpathname, is the only place where i need....i don`t know what to do

Comment: @Sebi95: You can use ASCII version of `GetFullPathName` - `GetFullPathNameA` it must work with simple `main`.

Comment: @Sebi95: But I still think that is something wrong with `arg[0]`, and strongly recomend you to make some debug output such as `consoleOut << argv[0] << std::endl;` to test correctness of your args.

Comment: With argv[0] there is not any problems, it works. I have problems with argv[1], argv[2] etc..

Comment: @Sebi95: Than try to output them. In for loop for example.

Comment: @Sebi95:  Ensure that your args is in the normal state. If not that OS didnot post comand args to app, and this is nothing wrong with your code.