# how to print a file path using GetFullPathName in c in windows

Tags: c, file, path, console

hope ur having good day;

so i am using GetFullPathName to get the path of powershell.exe in `C programming language` :

i used this code here :
[parsing a path using a functoin called getfullpathname() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460218/parsing-a-path-using-a-functoin-called-getfullpathname-in-c)
i used code here too:
[I have errors using GetFullPathName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365298/i-have-errors-using-getfullpathname)

whatever im using, im getting the following output:

```
Full path: C
```

if i debug it however i can see the rest of the path ...

last code i tried is:

```
    TCHAR* fileExt;
    TCHAR szDir[256];

    GetFullPathName("powershell.exe", 256, szDir, &fileExt);

    printf("Full path: %s\n", szDir);
```

i tried this for the same result:

```
   char filename[] = "powershell.exe";
   char fullFilename[MAX_PATH];
   GetFullPathName(filename, MAX_PATH, fullFilename, NULL);
   printf("Full path: %s\n", fullFilename);
```

i tried multiple code from here and there too, idk why but the output is always the same, and as i mentioned if i debug it i can see the full path, but i cant put it into the console, im using c and not cpp file , and using visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing mix and match between ansi and unicode.

Instead, do the following:

```
TCHAR* fileExt;
TCHAR szDir[256];

GetFullPathName(TEXT("powershell.exe"), 256, szDir, &fileExt);

_tprintf(TEXT("Full path: %s\n"), szDir);
```

The `TEXT` macro expands to either an ansi or wide character string literal, depending on whether or not you compile with `UNICODE` enabled.

`_tprintf` expands to either `printf` or `wprintf` depending on wether or not you compile with `UNICODE` enabled. For `printf`, `%s` specifies an ansi string, for `wprintf`, `%s` specifies a wide character string.

`GetFullPathName` expands to either `GetFullPathNameA` or `GetFullPathNameW`, again depending on wether or not you compile with UNICODE enabled. The former expects (and returns) ansi strings, the latter wide character strings.

Comment: first thanks for ur interest u and @andreas ... i tried doing it the same way u told me, but it outputted the following link error: ```LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tprintf```

Comment: the later code will create a powershell processes using CreateProcessA, so if that can ease the way the path file must be saved or the type of it ...

Comment: Well, then just use *GetFullPathNameA* and don't bother with *TCHAR* and both, ansi and unicode compatibility.