# How to display the value of a pointer In MFC?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a capture card from Black Magic Design company. In related document it is described that the `GetBytes` method, from `IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame` interface, allows direct access to the data buffer of a video frame. Here is my work:

```
HRESULT     DeckLinkDevice::VideoInputFrameArrived (/* in */ IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame* videoFrame, /* in */ IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket* audioPacket)
{
    char* str1;
    voidPtrToFrame = NULL;
    videoFrame->GetBytes(&voidPtrToFrame);
    sprintf(str1, "%p", voidPtrToFrame);
 // the below line does not work. 
    SetDlgItemText(m_uiDelegate->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_handytxtBox, str1);
}
```

I also defined `voidPtrToFrame` in class of `DeckLinkDevice`:

```
class DeckLinkDevice::IDeckLinkInputCallback
{
...
void* voidPtrToFrame;
...
}
```

In the last line an error appears related to `str1`:

> argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type
>   LPCWSTR

I want to know:

How can I display the value of `voidPtrToFrame` in an Edit control? i.e. I want to present the address of buffer containing the video frame. In the following image I provided the necessary information about `GetBytes` method.

[image]

I googled a lot and tested several ways. But I could not implement them in MFC.

Comment: This is unrelated to the Windows API, MFC, or even C++. It's really just about C, and pointers, uninitialized data and undefined behavior. You should read an introduction to C first, to understand, how it is different from managed execution environments (like .NET).

Comment: @IInspectable the `SetDlgItemText` part of the question *is* somewhat Windows related.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That call is unrelated to the issue at hand: Writing to memory pointed to by an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable there are actually two issues in this question, the second one is dealing with a compilation error in `SetDlgItemText`.

Comment: @IInspectable please consider that I did same work on win32 application successfully many times. I am new to MFC enviroment and its methods.

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that invalidates already published answers. Besides, you aren't even using anything MFC-specific here (with the exception of querying for a window handle). In this particular case, an application using the Windows API and an application using MFC are pretty much identical. You probably need to study the Windows API more to understand, how MFC fits into this. This question, however, isn't related to MFC at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char\[\] to LPCWSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225682/convert-char-to-lpcwstr)

Comment: @IInspectable I did not know there is `SetDlgItemText` in win32 application. I forgot typing `[100]` when declaring `str1`. Do NoT judge when you do NOT know me.

Comment: *"I did not know there is SetDlgItemText in win32 application."* - [SetDlgItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521.aspx) is exported from *user32.dll*. This is part of the Win32 subsystem (not MFC). *"I forgot typing `[100]` when declaring `str1`."* That's not a declaration but a definition. And defining an array still leaves its contents uninitialized. *"Do NoT judge when you do NOT know me."* - I do not have to know the author to judge the quality and accuracy of a question.

Comment: @IInspectable I learned from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

**1. You get a crash or at least undefined behaviour**

The variable `str1` is never initialized. It's a classic beginner's error.

The problem is here:

```
char* str1;
voidPtrToFrame = NULL;
videoFrame->GetBytes(&voidPtrToFrame);

// here str1 points to an interterminate location, it has never been
// initialized !! Therefore your program most likely will crash
sprintf(str1, "%p", voidPtrToFrame)
```

You need this:

```
char str1[20]; //<<< changement here

voidPtrToFrame = NULL;
videoFrame->GetBytes(&voidPtrToFrame);

// now str1 points to a 20 byte buffer
sprintf(str1, "%p", voidPtrToFrame);
```

**2. You must use wide characters**

You are compiling for unicode, therefore you need this (previous other corrections are included here):

```
wchar_t str1[20];

voidPtrToFrame = NULL;
videoFrame->GetBytes(&voidPtrToFrame);

wsprintf(str1, L"%p", voidPtrToFrame);
SetDlgItemText(m_uiDelegate->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_handytxtBox, str1);
```

Comment: It works fine. Many thanks for the reply. The value of `voidPtrToFrame` is varying continuously. Can I make it constant by `static` keyword? if yes, how to do?

Comment: No you can't because `voidPtrToFrame` is updated by the `GetBytes` function which is not under your control.