# Cannot convert const char* to PCWSTR after changing to Use Multi Byte Character Set

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to pass a const char* to a windows SetThreadDescription() function.

```cpp
int pthread_setname_np(HANDLE thread, const char* name) { 
     return SetThreadDescription(thread, name);
}
```

and I am getting an error

> 'HRESULT SetThreadDescription(HANDLE,PCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char *' to 'PCWSTR'

Of course I've stumbled into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732547/lpcwstr-to-char-and-vice-versa) and checked the character set and it was already set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set. Is there a way to fix this?

edit: add properties
[image]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it says it's undefined

Comment: The [`SetThreadDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription) function doesn't seem to exist in an "ASCII" (non-wide character) version. You need to convert the string to wide-character string and use that converted string in the call.

Comment: @Axalo Yes but shouldn't these functions be able to accept c style arguments like const char*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh that would probably be the reason. Where did you find that?

Comment: @IanPetek Apologies. it seems that SetThreadDescription is an exception to the normal way that the Windows API handles this. So I guess you will have to do to the conversions yourself using MultiByteToWideChar. Or switch to wide chars in the first place, which is best practise I think,

Comment: @IanPetek No, on Windows you'll have to get used to working with `wchar_t`. The ANSI variants have long been deprecated and applications should always call the Unicode variants directly. Newer functions such as `SetThreadDescription` don't even have an ANSI variant.

Comment: Because functions in the official Microsoft docs reference is listed explicitly with their ASCII or Wide versions. If you look at the function-list on the left side of the reference I link to you will see both `CreateProcessW` as well as `CreateProcessA` (for example). There just aren't any mentions of `SetThreadDescriptionA` or `SetThreadDescriptionW`. It might be because `SetThreadDescription` is too new?

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar it is

Answer (score 1):

@someprogrammerdude provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501684/cannot-convert-const-char-to-pcwstr-after-changing-to-use-multi-byte-character/74501795#comment131514704_74501684):

> The SetThreadDescription function doesn't seem to exist in an "ASCII" (non-wide character) version. You need to convert the string to wide-character string and use that converted string in the call.

Answer (score 0):

SetThreadDescription requires a unicode (two byte) description.
Thread names are often just constant strings.  If this is the case, just put an 'L' in front of the string.

```
PWSTR astring = L"a unicode description";
char *astring = "a description";
```