# argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, header

I have a very big problem... I' ve started today morning programming in Windows.h but I can't figure out why it gave me this problem as I litteraly copy the thing in the tut. (https://youtu.be/8GCvZs55mEM?t=5m20s) (I put the link to start the video when occurs my error)

The only thing I noticed is that in the tut it uses a LPCSTR variable for test, but my editor (Visual Studio Code) signal a LPCWSTR variable.

Sorry for the bad English.

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInts, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{

MessageBox(NULL, "Ciao!", "La prima GUI", MB_OK, );

return 0;
}
```

How can I solve?

In the comment:

Now the error don't show up, thanks a lot. But there is a problem... The editor don' t built the application. The Console give:

```
Executing task: g++ -g main.cpp -o Program <  
main.cpp: In function 'int WinMain(void *, void *, char *, int)':
main.coo:8: pasing '__wchar_t *' as argument 2 of 'MessageBox(void *, const char *, const char *, UINT)'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char\[\] to LPCWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225682/convert-char-to-lpcwstr)

Comment: The qick fix is to use wide string literals. Just put L infront if the strings. Like L"Ciao!"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you watch carefully, you can see that `MessageBox` is just a macro and on the video it is referred to `MessageBoxA` which is ANSI variant and will take `const char *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously not a good tutorial. Do it like like this

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Ciao!", L"La prima GUI", MB_OK);
```

Using `L` changes the string literal so that it uses wide characters. A wide character string literal can be converted to the type `LPCWSTR`, a normal string literal cannot.

Comment: Now the error don't show up, thanks a lot. But there is a problem... The editor don' t built the application. The Console give:          Executing task: g++ -g main.cpp -o Program <  (new line, I can' t do it in the comment lol..)  main.cpp: In function 'int WinMain(void *, void *, char *, int)': (new line) main.coo:8: pasing '__wchar_t *' as argument 2 of 'MessageBox(void *, const char *, const char *, UINT)'

Comment: @TommasoGiubilei, VS defines `UNICODE` by default. You should also define it when compiling.

Comment: it' s activated, in the file c_cpp_proprierties.json under the configuration Win32 there is:             "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],